# Is there away to return a value from in a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I am trying to get the page to render in my browser from the following code below in the promise because I only want to render it when the promise is resolved.However it keeps erroring and says that there is no render function. How do I return the following tag.

```
app.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
        accessToken = idToken;
        console.log(accessToken);
        config = {
            headers: {'Authorization': accessToken}
        };
        axios.get('http://localhost:4001/api/v1/page', config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return (
                        <h1> test </h1>
                    ); 
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
    });
```

Comment: well... you don't. That's just not possible. You don't want each call to .render to have to wait on an async call. The async call should instead cause a render to occur with the result.

Comment: How should I change my code to do this

Comment: A promise is a way to encapsulate a future value to an operation that could take a while to complete.  The return value of `axios.get()`, a Promise, is the value you may want to return here.  It'll then be up to whoever consumes this return value to use `.then()` to consume the actual future value.

Comment: How do I return axios.get